# How can I change the default locking shortcut in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

I would like to lock windows through keyboard shortcut "WIN + Z".

Is there a way to change the default keyboard shortcut to "WIN + Z" from "WIN + L"? I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: https://www.autohotkey.com/ should be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. You cannot change the shortcut, because it's built in to Windows.

You can, however, use tools like AutoHotkey (as @DavidPostill suggested) to do this. Other creative ways to "change" the shortcut can be found from this StackOverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301053/re-assign-override-hotkey-win-l-to-lock-windows

Answer (score 0):

[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) can easily do the job:

```
;press Win+Z to lock computer
#z::DllCall("LockWorkStation")
```

Install AutoHotkey, create a `.ahk` file with the above contents and double-click
it for testing. When working, it shows as a green `H` icon which you may
right-click and choose "Exit" to stop.

Once it's working, you may copy the file to the Startup folder.

The Current Users Startup folder in Windows 10 is located at:

```
C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

The All Users Windows 10 startup folder is located at:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp
```